# XAMARIN FORM : how to send message to specific number of watsapp

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have page in which i have image of watsapp icon. What i want is when i tap on that image it go to watsapp to specific number which will be our company number, so client can text us or send any image or file through watsapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be through the custom URL scheme as described here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Which basically tells you to open a URI like this: `whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!`. You can simply open it by calling to the `Device.OpenUri` method of Xamarin.Forms. This should work cross-platform for iOS and Android.

If you want to share a photo immediately this isn't possible as far as I know. It is possible to someone that is in your recent chats, by the sharing API, but to my knowledge you can't send it to a random number. At least not for iOS, it might be different for Android.